# CSS: Make right <div> expand to remaining space beside a non-fixed width left column

Tags: css, layout, html

I have two columns in my layout.  I'd like the right `<div>` to expand to fill the remaining space beside the left `<div>`.  However, I would like the left `<div>`'s width to be based on its content - I don't want to specify a specific pixel width or percentage.  In other words, no matter how wide the left column becomes, the right column should simply fill whatever horizontal room is left.

Is this possible with purely CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `float:left` for your left side div.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fjcqn/), I gave it 3 different size of left side div column.

Comment: Wow, I was definitely overthinking this problem.  Thanks.